# open native maps from webview

Tags: java, android

I have an app with a webview. The webview links to a mobile webpage where all links work correctly. When I click on a link in this webview, the link opens up in google maps inside the webview. Instead, I want the link to open up the native google maps app. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I have this code that I need to insert it to my code

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("geo:")) {
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }  
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

This is my code:

```
package com.company.test2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try @JavascriptInterface for this action ? is this your website can you add some javascript into that ?

Comment: yes  and the website i can add  if it helps

Answer (score 1):

To call android method from javascript you would need to make Javascriptinterface class and annotating method like @JavascriptInterface in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and bind it to webview like

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

and from javascript you can call it like

```
function showtoastfromsite(){
    Android.showToast("hello from website");
}
```

Comment: @hadyalzpen no problem if something goes wrong let me know